# Нахождение всех элементов в массиве

Tags: java

Вопрос, который не могу найти в интернете(что и не странно, ведь многие пользуются готовым методами) - как найти все одинаковые элементы в массиве бинарным поиском? 
Будет- ли бинарный поиск бинарным если я ограничу его `for-ом` при найденном первом элементе и "прошагаю" бинарным поиском поднимая левое "дно" до тех пор пока не вернется "`нет найденных элементов`"?

Или же это можно сделать другим способом не прибегая к `for`? Подскажите!

Поиск для крайне левого элемента -

```
public static int binary_search_leftmost(int[] A,int n,int T) {
        int L = 0;
        int R = n;
        while (L < R) {
            int m = ((L + R) / 2);
            if (A[m] < T){
                L = m + 1;
            } else {
                R = m;
            }
        }
        return L;
}
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9};
        System.out.println(binary_search_leftmost(arr,17,5));
    }
```

Дополнение -

```
static int binarySearchR(String[] arr, String x) 
    { 
        int l = 0, r = arr.length - 1; 
        while (l < r) { 
            int m = l + (r - l) / 2; 

            int res = x.compareTo(arr[m]); 

            if (res == 0) 
                return m; 

            if (res < 0) 
                r = m - 1;

            else
                 l = m + 1; ; 
        } 

        return -1; 
    }
```

Не понимаю как исправить чтобы находил крайней правый элемент.. если элемента 2, то находит второй, но если элементов 3 и более, то метод все равно находит только второй элемент идущий за первым..
Например: `{"aa","aa","aa","aa","bb","bb"}` - метод находит элемент с индексом 1, а нужно чтобы находил с индексом 3

Comment: Поиск для крайне левого элемента у вас уже есть, осталось написать поиск для крайне правого.

Comment: @tym32167 Он тоже есть, но как тогда потом? Ведь они будут просто находить всегда на одном и том же месте элементы? Или?

Comment: не запустите - не узнаете.

Comment: А что будет, если запустить этот поиск для значения, на единицу большего?

Comment: @tym32167 Будут правый и левый элемент. Да, можно потом их отнять друг от друга, но тогда и прибавлять один нужно, ведь 7 - 4 = 3, а там будет 4 элемента, тогда во все решение +1 сделать и все. Это все понятно. Также понятно, что если находится на 0 элементе и на последнем, то просто можно вывести последний + 1. Это все не проблема, но ЭФФЕКТИВНОЕ ЛИ ЭТО РЕШЕНИЕ или же можно решить лучше?

Comment: @MBo Будет, конечно же, другая позиция.. Я выше ответил одному участнику, чтобы не переписывать прочтите пж комментарий выше. Но будет ли то решение эффективное или же можно как-то решить лучше?

Comment: Два бинарных поиска - да эффективно. Из формулировки вопроса мне неясно, имелось ли в виду два поиска, или больше

Comment: @MBo Не могли бы Вы мне помочь исправить для поиска по String, так как с числами проблем нет, а вот по String находит только второй элемент, а не крайний правый.. как можно было бы это исправить? Код добавлю выше как дополнение

Comment: @tym32167 Не могли бы Вы мне помочь исправить для поиска по String, так как с числами проблем нет, а вот по String находит только второй элемент, а не крайний правый.. как можно было бы это исправить? Код добавлю выше как дополнение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int BSL(String A[], String key) 
{ 
    int m; 
    int l = 0, r = A.length; 

    while( r > l ) 
    { 
        m = l + (r - l)/2; 

        if( A[m].compareTo(key) < 0 ) 
            l = m + 1; 
        else
            r = m; 
    } 

    return l; 
} 

public static int BSR(String A[], String key) 
{ 
    int l = 0, r = A.length; 
    int m; 

    while( r > l) 
    { 
        m = l + (r - l)/2; 

        if( A[m].compareTo(key) > 0 ) 
            r = m; 
        else
            l = m + 1; 
    } 
    return r - 1; 

}

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
       String[] arr = {"aa","aa","bb","bb","bb","cc","cc"};
       int l = BSL(arr, "bb");
       int r = BSR(arr, "bb");
       System.out.println(l);
       System.out.println(r);

    }
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/sUqsm1)

```
2
4
```

Чуть более выгодно во втором поиске передавать уже найденный левый край.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Почему - то все равно не работает иногда, когда много элементов.. особенно когда они с индексами 0, 1 или в конце массива, то все равно выводит второй или третий искомый элемент, если искать справа.. Если элемент на индексе 0 левым поиском искать, то выводит почему-то индекс один и т.д.

Comment: Поправил, взял из вики

Comment: Топ, спасибо)))

Comment: извиняюсь, за повторный вопрос, но как сделать так, чтобы выводило null или -1 если нет элемента. Метод выводит числа не соответствующие действительно, когда элемента не существует.. Пробовал сделать чтобы при L больше R выводило -1, но тогда метод полностью работает неправильно

Comment: Не понимаю, как это мешает. Я удалил из массива "aa" и запустил поиск по ним же. Получил 0,-1, и количество элементов ` -1 - 0 + 1 = 0`. Всё нормально. И с поиском "dd" тоже.

Comment: @странно, я создал большой массив для поиска с разной сложностью. И при вводе несуществующих элементов для поиска иногда просто выдает или 7, или 12 и т.д., не смотря на то, что элемента не существует

Comment: Поиск левый выдаёт место, на которое должен быть вставлен элемент, правый - на единицу левее. В приведённом коде, если искать bc, то вернётся 5 4 - тоже ожидаемо

Comment: Да это то понятно, но вот если элемента вообще нет, то возвращает странные числа

Comment: Я привёл пример, когда элемента нет